# Error found after importing archive file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, archive

I am a very beginner in android development using eclipse..
I have given an assignment to modify the android application made by a professor..
so I downloaded the file and imported it to eclipse.
My professor can normally run the program..
however, when I tried to test it before modication using simulator, " the application is forced to stop unexpectedly" is shown..
Moreover, I found that all .java file in src contained "x" ...and the codes in the .java file, like "import android.graphics" or "private class xxx" all contained error..which i have been told that "import andorid.graphics" cannot be resolved..
Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the codes...
and kindly provide me the procedures to fix this problem?

is it possible for me to send the zip file to someone..so that he/she can help me find out the problem??

Comment: provide us that exception which show in DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Android sdk and ADT are configured properly in Eclipse and you have updated the relevant packages using SDK Manager. Best way to test this is to create a [HelloWorld Android app](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: i think I have sucessfully configured it..since I could run other projects normally..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly installed the same Android SDK that your professor is using, the first thing to try is to right click on the project name, then select Android > Fix Project Properties.

I've often found that importing existing Android projects into a workspace can be problematic, especially when the project comes from a different machine. A work-around is to create a new Android project, then copy all the sources and resource files into the new project. It's a pain, but it avoids many problems that arise due to different development configurations.

Comment: i have tried the method by right click and fix project properties...but it still doesnt work...im just wondering why all import android.xxx that written on the top of each .java contained an x...is it something missed to be imported into eclipse..??

Comment: @ChunWaiWong If you mean that there are "x" characters in the text of each .java file, then there's something wrong with the download. Check with your professor.